# Eliminate Intermediate Eigen Arrays

Tags: c++, eigen

Does Eigen make any intermediate array for calculation of x or Eigen just put the values into simd registers and do the calculation?

In general, how to know how many intermediates did Eigen make?

Will Eigen allocate new memory for the intermediates in every cycle of the loop?

Is there anyway to ensure that eigen would not make any intermediate? Does it have a macro like "EIGEN_NO_INTERMEDIATE"?

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
void fill(T& x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) x.data()[i] = i + 1;
}

int main() {
    int n = 10;  // n is actually about 400
    ArrayXXf x(n, n);
    ArrayXf y(n);
    fill(x);
    fill(y);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {  // many cycles
        x = x * ((x.colwise() / y).rowwise() / y.transpose()).exp();
    }
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I guess it allocates new memory in every cycle: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=469

Comment: Maybe in the far future, compilation would give messages enclosed by a special tag.  Then a parser can convert the messages to a graphviz graph to show the intermediates and code paths.

Comment: I think if Eigen is creating any temporaries it's because they're seen as necessary by library developers - nobody generates temporaries knowing that they are redundant, so I wouldn't expect such a switch. I'd guess that it's got less to do with Eigen developers intentionally creating intermediates than with the compiler making optimizations.

Comment: Eigen chooses when to make intermediates. It has an internal cost model: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html

Comment: Isn't it the role of the optimizing compiler to take care of the loops?

Comment: Eigen use meta-programming. It changes the program before it gets feed to the compiler. So, it choose when to make intermediates. It is described in the link. Problem is if Eigen make intermediate and memory allocation within the loop, performance of the loop is dead. I think it can't sense the for loop exists because it doesn't have template to sense it. That means if it allocates any memory for intermediates, it will do it within the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a hook into the `DenseStorage` constructor like so:

```
#include <iostream>

static long int nb_temporaries;
inline void on_temporary_creation(long int size) {
  if(size!=0) nb_temporaries++;
}

// must be defined before including any Eigen header!
#define EIGEN_DENSE_STORAGE_CTOR_PLUGIN { on_temporary_creation(size); }

#define VERIFY_EVALUATION_COUNT(XPR,N) {\
    nb_temporaries = 0; \
    XPR; \
    if(nb_temporaries!=N) { std::cerr << "nb_temporaries == " << nb_temporaries << "\n"; }\
  }

#include <Eigen/Core>
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
void fill(T& x) { for(int i=0; i<x.size(); ++i) x(i)= i+1; }

int main() {
    int n=10;
    ArrayXXf x(n,n); fill(x);
    ArrayXf y(n); fill(y);

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        VERIFY_EVALUATION_COUNT( x = x * ((x.colwise()/y).rowwise()/y.transpose()).exp(), 0);
    }
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Essentially, this is what Eigen does in its testsuite at some points:
See [here for the original definition in the testsuite](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/8d1ccfd9c5/test/main.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#main.h-80) and [here for an example usage in the testsuite](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/8d1ccfd9c5/test/ref.cpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ref.cpp-179).

Alternatively, if you only care about intermediate memory allocations, you can try the macro [`EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html#TopicPreprocessorDirectivesDevelopers) -- this would allow fixed-sized expressions to evaluate into temporaries, as they would only allocate on the stack.

Comment: For n=1000, it didn't print the `nb_temporaries == ` line. I guess there is no intermediate array in this case. That is reassuring. Thanks.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb Eigen never creates temporaries for coefficient-wise operations like yours.